# UITableView is not getting reloaded after saving data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios6

Below is what I have on my screen (I have tried to show what I see on screen)

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+                                +
+  TextField-Name                +
+                                +
+  Save Button                   +
+                                +
+  UITableView                   +
+  .                             +
+  .                             +
+  .                             +
+                                +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

When I click save button the data get stored and I am showing the same in the table view that I have at below. The problem is when click save, data gets saved, however it is not showing in `UITableView`. I believe `[self.myTableView reloadData];` will do the trick however it is not doing.

Below is code I have.

**.h file**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DeviceDetailViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *nameTextField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;

- (IBAction)save:(id)sender;

@end
```

**.m file**

```
@interface DeviceDetailViewController ()
@end

@implementation DeviceDetailViewController
@synthesize myTableView;

- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
    // code for saving data
    NSLog(@"saved data and now reload data.... started....");
    [self.myTableView reloadData];
    // I thought this statement will do magic... but its not....
    NSLog(@"saved data and now reload data.... finised....");
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    NSLog(@"numberOfRowsInSection %d", self.devices.count);
    return self.devices.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cel3";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [myTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    NSManagedObject *device = [self.devices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"cellForRowAtIndexPath %@ %@ by %@", [device valueForKey:@"name"], [device valueForKey:@"version"], [device valueForKey:@"company"]);
    [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [device valueForKey:@"name"], [device valueForKey:@"version"]]];
    [cell.detailTextLabel setText:[device valueForKey:@"company"]];

    return cell;
}
```

When I run app, below is what I get in `NSLOG`

```
2012-12-31 11:52:34.222 MyStore[720:11603] numberOfRowsInSection 0
2012-12-31 11:52:34.627 MyStore[720:11603] numberOfRowsInSection 2
2012-12-31 11:52:34.628 MyStore[720:11603] cellForRowAtIndexPath iPhone 4s by Apple
2012-12-31 11:52:34.629 MyStore[720:11603] cellForRowAtIndexPath X10 Mini Pro by Sony
```

When I add something, I get

```
2012-12-31 11:53:21.868 MyStore[720:11603] saved data and now reload data.... started....
2012-12-31 11:53:21.869 MyStore[720:11603] numberOfRowsInSection 2
2012-12-31 11:53:21.870 MyStore[720:11603] saved data and now reload data.... finised....
2012-12-31 11:53:21.871 MyStore[720:11603] cellForRowAtIndexPath iPhone 4s by Apple
2012-12-31 11:53:21.872 MyStore[720:11603] cellForRowAtIndexPath X10 Mini Pro by Sony
```

That means all methods are getting called, still I am not getting data.

Could someone point what additional code do I need to write?

Comment: did you integrate delegates with tableview?if yes are you getting your desired content in self.devices?

Comment: Did cellForRowAtIndexPath method called? after reload the table

Comment: if you are using client server...then the time to go..update...come...and then reload table is much slower than [reload table]. either you can do synchronous call or a timer to wait.

Comment: @ForamMukundShah : When I run app again, I see data in list... but when I add new, I don't come direclty...

Comment: did you try to log self.devices after adding new object?

Answer (score 1):

As your `table` `dataSource` array is `self.devices` array.

The reason might be `self.devices` array `doesnot` get `updated`when `saving data`

So firstly `update` `self.devices` then `reload table`.

Comment: thanks. your answer is also right, but didn't get hint. so +1 for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with your **`cellForRowAtIndexPath`** method try to use the following lines of code

**

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
```

**

instead of

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cel3";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [myTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```